# A little too much spacing between developer story on jobs vs on companies

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs

When viewing Developer Jobs via search jobs:

[image]

When viewing via search companies:

[image]

Please fix immediately!

Comment: [A difference of 8px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBMrq.png), to be precise.

Comment: +1 for clear marking and marvelous red arrows with drop shadow. Now I know where to look at :)

Comment: Needs more free-hand circles...

Comment: Spacer div is back!

Comment: Please fix immediately!??????????? It is just a small bug and almost no people notice it..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your bug report.  I have now added the eight pixels of space to the "search companies" view as well, so the spacing should now be consistent between the two views.

And, yes, I used a spacer `<div>` rather than, say, changing some CSS.  Doing so was necessary — or at least simpler — due to how the banner area is rendered on the backend.